# Firestore Group by field

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js

Below is my firestore collection structure

[image]

My vue method to get data

```
fetchResults(){
  db.collection('data').onSnapshot((querySnapShot)=>{
    let results = [];
    querySnapShot.forEach(doc=>{
      results.push(doc.data())
    })
    this.record=results;
  })
}
```

What I want is to query in the document like `group by ID and order by sec_id desc`.

How do I suppose to query like that?

So that I will get document grouped by ID field.

Comment: `db.collection('data').orderBy('id').orderBy('sec_id', desc)` don't work?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer The result should only be unique ID rows which would be grouped in my case

Comment: Maybe this video helps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As a NoSQL type database, Cloud Firestore doesn't offer any aggregation queries such as grouping, sum, max, etc.  You have to perform these operations in your client code.  For your case, this means you will have to query for all the documents in the collection, then group them by whatever fields you want.  Alternatively, you can maintain a separate collection of pre-grouped  documents to satisfy your query. (Duplicating data like this is common in NoSQL type databases.)

Comment: Oh didn't know - Duplicating data like this is common in NoSQL type databases. And one more doubt - `you have to perform these operations in your client code` - what will happen if it returns huge amount of data to client code without grouping. Isn't it huge memory consumption  in client side

Comment: You will need enough memory to store all the documents in memory, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do using

```
fetchResults(){
  db.collection('data')
 .orderBy("id", "asc")
 .onSnapshot((querySnapShot)=>{
     // Do something
  })
}
```

More information visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data and you can also apply filter using click on click on **filter icon**[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calculating the data with an aggregate query, the data should be saved in the document itself using client side logic to update the aggregate data each time the document is changed or use cloud functions.

See this post from Google blog.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation

Answer (score 0):

I'm too late, but if anyone looking for easier solution, I would suggest you to use lodash for grouping, in below example I'm grouping sales based on the Order Date.

```
import { mapValues, groupBy, omit } from "lodash";

export const salesTrend = async () => {
    const orderData: any[] = [];
    const orderResponse = await getDocs(collectionRef);
    const orders = orderResponse.docs
    orders.forEach(order => orderData.push(order.data()))
    let grouped = mapValues(groupBy(orderData, 'orderDate'),
        clist => clist.map(car => omit(car, 'orderDate'))
    );
    console.log(grouped);
}
```